# Regular expression matching strings where it contains a specific word that has a period

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to write a regular expression that matches string that contain a certain word with a period for example (apple. or grape.). I got it to work without the period but not quite sure how to get it to work when there is a period in the word.

What I tried:

```
(?i)\b(Apple|Grape)\b (Working correctly without the period)
(?i)\b(Apple\.|Grape\.)\b (Returns no matches)
```

**Sample strings that should work:**

```
1 apple.
1 Apple.
apple. 2
grape. 1
test grape.
grape. test
this is a Apple. test
```

**Sample strings that should not work:**

```
1apple.
1Apple.
apple.2
grape.1
testgrape.
grape.test
longwordApple.test
this is a Apple.test
```

Comment: Are you wanting to detect if a string contains the pattern or every occurrence of the pattern?

Comment: Split it over space and match the entire word? O(n) complexity

Comment: `.matches("(?i)(.* )?(Apple\\.|Grape\\.)( .*)?")` Returns true if `apple.` or `grape.` (in any letter case) is found to be within a string or on their own.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_regex.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write the pattern as:

```
\b(Apple|Grape)\.(?!\S)
```

**Explanation**

- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial word match on the left
- `(Apple|Grape)` Capture either Apple or Grape
- `\.` Match a dot
- `(?!\S)` Assert a whitespace boundary to the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TvRO2U/1)

In Java with the double escaped backslashes:

```
String regex = "(?<!\\S)(Apple|Grape)\\.(?!\\S)";
```

Comment: What about a Whitespace boundary to the left? I am not very good at regexes, so I am guessing the \b will take care of it?

Comment: @justanotherguy It depends on what you want to allow at the left. In that case it can be `(?<!\S)(Apple|Grape)\.(?!\S)`

Comment: @justanotherguy the \b (word boundary) covers begin/end string, whitespace, and termination punctuation like . ! ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you need regexes? I mean I can think of a normal tokenization parser on the following lines:

```java
String s = "";
foreach(String token : s.split(" ")) { // I suggest saving the split (apparently, javac does not do a good job at caching like the C/C++ compiler)
    if(token.equals("apple.") || token.equals("grapes.")) { // or take in a word array with all matches and then run it over all those (n^2 complexity)
        
        //whatever you wanna do
    }
}
```